# Using ExecuteSqlCommand to create stored procedures from text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute an sql text file to create stored procedures on an sql server db. I'm also using this method to create user defined table types, which the stored procedure(s) will use.

The creation of the table types works perfectly. However, when I go to create the stored procedure I'm getting the error, 
     'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Here is the code which reads the file and executes it against the db:

```
public static void LoadStoredProcedures()
    {
        const string procedureLocation = "C:\\StoredProcedures.txt";

        var reader = File.ReadAllText(procedureLocation);

        var context = new prismEntities();
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(reader);


    }

    public static void CreateTables()
    {
        const string tableLocation = "C:\\CreateTables.txt";

        var reader = File.ReadAllText(tableLocation);

        var context = new prismEntities();
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(reader);
    }
```

an example of the user defined table:

```
if not exists (select * from sys.table_types
where name like 'TextbookTable')
create type [dbo].[TextbookTable] as table (
[TXUID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SKU] [int] NOT NULL,
[UsedSKU] [int] NOT NULL,
[BindingID] [int] NOT NULL,
[TextStatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
[StatusDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Author] [char](45) NOT NULL,
[Title] [char](80) NOT NULL,
[ISBN] [char](30) NULL,
[Imprint] [char](10) NULL,
[Edition] [char](2) NULL,
[Copyright] [char](2) NULL,
[Type] [char](10) NULL,
[Bookkey] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Weight] [decimal](10, 4) NULL,
[ImageURL] [char](128) NULL,
primary key clustered
(
    [TXUID] ASC
) with (ignore_dup_key = on)
)
```

an example of the stored procedure I'm attempting to create :

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[AddTextbook]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure [dbo].[AddTextbook]

create procedure [dbo].[AddTextbook]
(
@textbook TextbookTable readonly
)
as
begin
set nocount on;
set identity_insert textbook on

begin try

merge Textbook txt
using (select * from @textbook) as source
    on txt.TXUID = source.TXUID
when not matched then
    insert (TXUID, SKU, UsedSKU, BindingID, TextStatusID, StatusDate, Author,
            Title, ISBN, Imprint, Edition, Copyright, Type, Bookkey, Weight, ImageURL)
    values ( source.TXUID, source.SKU, source.UsedSKU, source.BindingID, source.TextStatusID,
             source.StatusDate, source.Author, source.Title, source.ISBN,
             source.Imprint, source.Edition,
             source.Copyright, source.Type, source.Bookkey, source.Weight, source.ImageURL);

set identity_insert textbook off    
end try

begin catch
    declare @message varchar(128) = error_message()
    select
     ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber,
     ERROR_SEVERITY() as ErrorSeverity,
     ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
     ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
     ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine,
     ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
     raiserror(@message, 16, 10)
end catch
end

grant execute on [dbo].[AddTextbook] to [public]
```

Now, the order of the calls, is the CreateTables is called first then the LoadStoredProcedures. The tables get created with no problems. The stored procedures do not get created and generate the above mentioned error. I have removed the 'if exists...' line and the stored procedure will get created, however, if there are others that I'm trying to create in the same file, they will error out and not get created. I want to be able to manage this with one file, not multiple ones for each stored procedure.

Does anyone know a work around for this? Hopefully I have provided ample information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're missing a bunch of `GO` statements between command such as:

You have to change

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[AddTextbook]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure [dbo].[AddTextbook]

create procedure [dbo].[AddTextbook]
```

To be

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[AddTextbook]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure [dbo].[AddTextbook]
GO
create procedure [dbo].[AddTextbook]
```

Comment: Doesn't he also need a `GO` before the Grant?

Comment: As a note to the OP, you could have probably discovered the issues by placing your scripts in a query window and executing them in SSMS. Generally, if you're passing SQL statements that fail via code, those same statements will fail running in SSMS.

Comment: The GO generates the following error: "Incorrect syntax near 'go'"

Comment: I have copied the SP directly from SSMS. They work perfectly from there.

Comment: Well, since I can't answer my own question yet, I did come up with a solution. I just wrote a method which would break the text file into a list based on the GO statement. Then executed each statement with success. Thanks everyone.

Comment: GO is not a valid SQL command. It is something built into SSMS parsing of the SQL within the window.