# How to run raw SQL queries with temp tables within Entity Framework context?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Due to performance reasons, I need to run the following raw SQL on an EF DbContext. I cannot use a stored procedure as I don't have control over the DB. How do I do write the following raw query?

```
Declare @Results table ([Result] varchar(100));

Insert into @Results ([Result])
Values ('somevalue'),  ('manymorelikethis');

SELECT
    [Attribute1],
    [Attribute2],
    FROM   [Table1]
    ...
    JOIN [SometTable] ON ...
                Inner join @Results p on p.Result = [SomethingElse]
                WHERE (somecondition)
```

Comment: Try `ExecuteSqlCommand` method with `SqlParameter`: `using (var db = new DataContext()) { db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand([commandtext], [parameters]); }`.

Comment: How do I do the Insert query snippet using parameters? I need to dynamically construct the values. The number of entries in not known before hand.

Comment: You can create a `DataTable` that has same structure as your TVP (e.g. `var dt = new DataTable();`) & declaring `SqlParameter` like this: `var parameter = new SqlParameter("@values", SqlDbType.Structured);` & `parameter.Value = dt;`. This may help you finding out how to use TVP in EF: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/78607b/using-table-valued-parameters-in-entity-framework/.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto OP does not have control over DB and your suggestion requires a custom type in database. Even though this is the right solution, this might not work for OP.

Comment: AFAIK, TVP usually passed with a stored procedure, so that how about using workaround for `ExecuteSqlCommand` like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692996/using-executesqlcommand-to-create-stored-procedures-from-text-file? You may use command strings or predefined text file containing SQL commands (including `CREATE PROCEDURE`) to be passed into `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Comment: Have you tried `values ('{0}'), ('{1}'), ...` and pass the values as an array to `ExecuteSqlCommand` in the second param.

Comment: you can use in following way:
 `parameterList = new List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter>()
            {
                new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter(){
                ParameterName = "@param",
                Value = 1
                }
            };
            
            var result = context.Database.SqlQuery(t, $"{tempTableSql}", parameters: parameterList.ToArray());`

But I dont think you can use created temptable in next request not sure you can try